# "System.OutOfMemoryException" in C# Visual Studio 2019 large elements

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I need to initialize 2-d array with .6 billion * 10-k element but I end up with

> System.OutOfMemoryException

I am using C# Visual Studio 2019.

I pasted the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>` in `app.config`.

Comment: The answer is simple: you cannot do this. 6 billion * 10 thousand = 50+ Terabyte. You cannot allocate 50+ TB on your memory :) Even if you found a magical way to do it, this code would take centuries to execute.

Comment: If you explained why you think you need to do this we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you have all the memory available.

```
6billion*10k*4byte/int= 240000 GB
```